# Standard registration and logging in Laravel - adding a logo in the activation email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm beginner in Laravel. I have project in Laravel 5.8. I use in my project standard Laravel registration and login system.

I have a question, I would like to add the logo of my application to the activation email.

I would like to replace the standard "Application name" in the email logo of the application.

How can I do this?

Comment: You have to edit email template https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#configuring-the-view

Comment: Edit resources/views/auth/passwords/email.blade.php and resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php these two files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Take a look I hope its help you.**

> I write this as answer because my reputation is low for comment

Customizing Laravel’s default notification email template (Adding a logo and changing colours/style)

https://medium.com/@christianjombo/customizing-laravels-default-notification-email-template-adding-a-logo-and-changing-ff6f107dd640